# Windows 10 fall creators update - Certain desktop icons not displaying?

Tags: windows-10, icons, desktop

A few days ago, i factory reset my gaming rig. It came from the factory running classic windows 10. It was later upgraded to anniversary (which was amazing and ran Very well) And was recently upgraded to creators. Creators update has given me lots of issues, mainly on the desktop. My One Drive was syncing my desktop, which would remove my steam shortcuts and would leave behind other icons. I don't know why this is happening and yet other icons are staying. If anyone can help than please do as this is annoying as ****!!!!

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps don't do that, syncing the desktop? Desktop is not the place to save your data anyway...

Comment: I wasn't saving my data to the desktop. Only my shortcuts to programs. I also signed out of OneDrive because i don't use it and that worked. Thanks @MichaelBay